# How I can display all users in a selection box with items for another model? asp.net mvc core 3.1

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-3.0

**this model for users**

```
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{ 
   [PersonalData]
   public string FirstName { get; set; }

   [PersonalData]
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

---

**and model course**

```
public class Course
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CourseTitel { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

---

**and create page**

```
@model mycenter1.Models.Course


<div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="UserId" class="control-label"></label>
      <select asp-for="UserId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.UserId"></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to make a ViewModel which will look like this:

```
public class CourseViewModel
{    
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string CourseTitel { get; set; }
  public string UserId { get; set; }
  public string SelectedUserId { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> AllUsers {get; set; }
}
```

And in your View:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label asp-for="UserId" class="control-label"></label>
  <select asp-for="SelectedUserId" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.AllUsers, "Id", "FirstName"))">
  </select>
</div>
```